# Solving complex number equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

Number of values of x (real or complex) simultaneously satisfying the system of equations
$1 + z + z^2
 + z^3
 + .......... + z^{17} = 0$ and $1 + z + z^2
 + z^3
 + .......... + z^{13} = 0$ is?

I tried to solve it by subtracting the second equation from the first and thus getting  $z^{14}+ z^{15} + z^{16} + z^{17}=0$.Now -1 and i can satisfy the equation but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If you write $0 = z^{14} + z^{15} + z^{16} + z^{17} = z^{14}(1+z+z^2+z^3)$, can you make progress?

Comment: Maybe it helps to note that $1+z+\dots+z^n=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a moderate simplification:
\begin{equation}0 = z^{14} + z^{15} + z^{16} + z^{17} = z^{14}(1+z+z^2+z^3)\end{equation}
For this to be true, either $z^{14} = 0$ (in which case $z=0$), or
\begin{equation}1+z+z^2+z^3=0.\end{equation}
Since
\begin{equation}
1+z+z^2+z^3 = \frac{z^4-1}{z-1},
\end{equation}
you must have $z^4-1 = 0$.  Hence $z$ must be a fourth root of unity, i.e. $z = \pm 1$, or $z=\pm i$.  But we can't have $z=1$ (this would "break" the fraction), and leaving the three roots $z=-1,i,-i$ (you can check these by hand easily enough, but writing
\begin{equation}
1+z+z^2+z^3 = \frac{z^4-1}{z-1} = \frac{(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)(z-i)}{z-1} = (z+1)(z+i)(z-i)
\end{equation}
should be convincing enough.)

Comment: I think you mean $z = 1$ would break the function (since you are dividing by $z-1$

Comment: Yarp.  Damn dyslexia.  Thanks.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but how did you get 1+z+z^2+z^3=(z^4-1)/(z-1).

Comment: @PragatiJoshi I can't remember how one is meant to derive that fact, but it is fairly easy to check that it works out via division (are you familiar with either polynomial long division or synthetic division?).  Actually... now that I think about it, take $z^n - 1$.  Since $(1)^n - 1 = 0$, we know that $z=1$ is one factor.  Divide $z^n-1$ by $z-1$ to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The new equation is $z^{14}(1+z+z^2+z^3)=0$. The roots of this are $z=0$ and $z=+-i$ $z=-1$

Now check those in one of the original equations.

$z=0$ doesn't work

The original equations are divisors of $z^{14}-1$ and $z^{18}-1$ respectively. This helps check. The extra factor being $z-1$

$z=i$ doesn't make $z^{18}-1$ vanish

$z=-i$ doesn't make $z^{18}$ vanish

Finally, $z=-1$ works and it is not z=1.

........................

Method 2.

Compute the gcd of $z^{18}-1$ and $z^{14}-1$. Divide the gcd by $z-1$, which is the extra factor we included and look at the degree. That is the number of common roots.

$gcd=z^2-1$

Divided by $z-1$ is $z+1$, which has only one root.

Comment: You may want to add some `$` s around your maths. [$\LaTeX$ tips](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: `z^{18}` is what you are looking for, the brackets group things together so $\LaTeX$ knows that they are all together

Answer (score 2):

We subtract $z^4(1+z+\ldots +z^{13})=0$ from $1+z+\ldots +z^{17}=0$ and get $1+z+z^2+z^3=0$.

Then we subtract $(z^2+z^6+z^{10})(1+z+z^2+z^3)=0$ from $1+z+\ldots +z^{13}=0$ and we get $z+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1}={z^n-1\over z-1}$$
the solutions of the first equation are the vertices of a regular $18$-gon on $S^1$ with one vertex at $1$, apart from this very vertex. Similarly, the solution of the second equation are the vertices of a regular $14$-gon, apart from the vertex $1$. The two polygons have exactly one more vertex in common, namely $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions to the first equation are the elements $\ne 1$ of the multiplicative group $U_{18}$ (the $18$-th roots of unity in $\mathbf C$), i.e. $\;\Bigl\{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ki\pi}{18}} \:\Big\vert\: 1\le k\le 17 \Bigr\}$. Similarly the solutions to the second equation are the elements $\ne1$ of the group $\; U_{14}=\Bigl\{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\ell i\pi}{14}}\:\Big\vert\: 1\le \ell\le 13\Bigr\}$.

The common solutions, plus $1$ are just the intersection of the subgroups $$U_{18}\cap U_{14}=U_{\gcd(18,14)}=U_2=\{-1,1\}.$$
Thus the only common solution of the given equations is $-1$.